# How can I save data into DB on Django exit

Tags: python, mysql, django, caching

First, I'm a C++ developer new to Python and Django.
Second, I'm a client developer new to server developing.

Now for some reasons I have to develop a server, and I choose Python, Django and MySQL.

I have objects of a class to store data from db as cache. And I want to automatically write data into db before the the object will be deleted. Here is the code:

```
class Gamer:

    def __init__(self, uuid):
        self._uuid = uuid
        self._account = _get_account(uuid)

    def __del__(self):
        self.save()

    def save(self):
        self._account.save()


def _get_account(uuid):
try:
    account = Account.objects.get(uuid=uuid)
    return account
except ObjectDoesNotExist:
    account = Account.create(uuid)
    account.save()
    return account
except MultipleObjectsReturned:
    assert False
    print 'Fatal error - two accounts exist with same UUID:' + uuid
    return Account.objects.filter(uuid=uuid)[0]
```

Here's the problem:

Once the save method was called when I turned Django server off. An error would occur and nothing was saved into db. Console info:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'db_for_write'" in <bound method Gamer.__del__ of <player.gamer.Gamer instance at 0x10a8c1d40>> ignored
```

But in other cases, the save method works well.

I suppose some thing connect db with Django was released before the **del** method was called. But how can I reach my purpose? Or how to solve this problem?

By the way, Anyone has some suggest about db caching in Django?

Comment: I don't understand this question. What is calling a save method if the server is turned off? Why is this even an issue?

Comment: I mean when I turn the server off by myself, I hope I can save cache data into DB automatically before the server is shut down. So I use cache object's destructor to do the job. But when I turned the server off, the exception I mentioned above was thrown and nothing in cache was saved into DB.